# How can I detect if there was a change on the transform rotation on the y only?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Tried to search in google but could not find any solution.

I don't have yet any code that I tried.
I want in the update to check that if there was a change on the transform rotation on the Y only than do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Transform.hasChanged](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-hasChanged.html) in your Update() loop. When it changes, store the last known y value, then compare it the next time it changes.